# Difference between .subscribe(x=> ...) and .subscribe(next(...))?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to test the output of a Subject `symbol$` that exists on my component.
Specifically, Subject symbol$ should emit (is this the right word here?) a value whenever the component property `symbol` has changed.

However, I could not find a way to test the output to `symbol$` until I came across a chunk of code online that uses the .subscribe(next() { ... }) instead of .subscribe((x) => {...}); syntax.

What is the difference between the 2 calls?
And why does only 1 of these work?

```
it('should fetch data', () => {
  const actuals: string[] = [];

  // commented version doesn't work
  // component.symbol$.subscribe((symbol) => { actuals.push(symbol); } ;

  component.symbol$.subscribe({
    next(symbol) {
      actuals.push(symbol);
    },
  });

  expect(actuals).toEqual(['']);
  component.symbol = 'IBM';
  component.ngOnChanges();

  expect(actuals).toEqual(['', 'IBM']);
});
```

Comment: Does your actual code contain the missing parenthesis at the end of `component.symbol$.subscribe((symbol) => { actuals.push(symbol); } ;` ?

Comment: @avalerio all 3 functions are optional and you can actually `subscribe()` without passing any parameter. There is no difference between passing an object with 3 potential properties like this `{next: d => {// do stuff at each notification}, error: err => {// handle error}, complete: () => {// do stuff at completion}` and passing 3 functions, the first one for the `next` case, the second for the `error` case and the third for `complete` case.

Comment: @Picci Yea forgot about the empty subscribe. But you're right there is effectively no difference between the two lines. Although personally I think the 3 function solution is much more readable. I have deleted my comment as yours is a much better explanation.

Comment: I have to ask, is there a way that the community leans when deciding to use a single arrow function `.subscribe( value => {...})` vs using the next pattern arrow function `.subscribe( {next: value => {...} })` ? What is the general best practice here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There *is* a difference in passing arrow functions vs normal functions into the subscribe, specifically around *this*.

Observer with Arrow Functions:
[image]

Observer with Function Declarations:
[image]

But watch out for `this`:

```
const sub = source$.subscribe({
  next(apple) { this.apple = apple }, // Does NOT reference the 
                                      // class-level variable
  error(err) { console.log(`Error occurred: ${err}`)},
  complete() { console.log(`No more apples, go home`)}
});
```

Since `this` is scoped to a function, the `this` within the `next(apple)` function will *not* reference any class-level variable but will assume you are defining a new variable local to the `next(apple)` function.

That is not the case with arrow functions. `this` within an arrow function is scoped to the class-level variable.

Comment: thanks! I didn't think that arguments would be affected by the difference between named / anonymous function

Comment: The arguments themselves aren't affected, only any variables referenced with *this*.